# Best way to check optional module availability

Tags: module, raku

In a module I'm writing there is just one method which requires an additional module, so I wish to make that module optional by not listing it in the `depends` part of the META6.json file. The method will return a Failure object if the optional module is not available.
I know I can do something like this:

```
if (try require Optional::Module) !=== Nil {
  # go on
} else {
  # fail
}
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I think you should be able to use `if $*REPO.candidates('Optional::Module')` or similar, though I couldn't seem to get it to work on my sister. but honestly, unless you're doing it many many times, I think `(try require Foo) !=== Nil` is about as simple and unfussy as you can get.

Comment: `.candidates` currently only works on CURI and CURFS, so using it would be more like `say so $*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.?candidates(...).Slip).grep(*.defined)`. One could use `.resolve` directly on `$*REPO` instead, but its probably not any shorter: `say so $*REPO.resolve(CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name("Optional::Module")))`

Comment: @ugexe thanks!  I wasn't sure the exact syntax, but I figured whatever it is, it's not really much simpler than the `try require Foo`.  Perhaps with macros someoe could make an `available Foo` macro that rewrites into the `try require` bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to thank everyone who answered or commented on this question.
I benchmarked my proposed solution and the two ones given in the comments to my question:

```
my $pre = now;
for ^10000 {
  $*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.?candidates('Available::Module').Slip).grep(*.defined);
  $*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.?candidates('Unavailable::Module').Slip).grep(*.defined);
}
say now - $pre; # 13.223087

$pre = now;
for ^10000 {
  $*REPO.resolve(CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name("Available::Module")));
  $*REPO.resolve(CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name("Unavailable::Module")));
}
say now - $pre; # 3.105257

$pre = now;
for ^10000 {
  (try require Available::Module) !=== Nil;
  (try require Unavailable::Module) !=== Nil;
}
say now - $pre; # 4.963793
```

Change the module names to match one that you have available on your system and one that you don't.
The comments show the results in seconds on my computer.

Comment: So I noodled about with this and wonder. Did you try something like `so $*REPO.installed.first( { $_.meta<name> ~~ "Module" }).elems` ? Just see if the module is in the list of installed ones? Not sure how fast that would be.

Comment: That's super quick if you cache the `$*REPO.installed` sequence (maybe in a state var?) and super duper slow otherwise. (The try require 10000 times on my machine took ~12 seconds. The first from the installed list took ~0.6)

Comment: …and slow it is: when the benchmark finally ended it totaled 1229 seconds.
Thanks anyway, it's good to know!

Comment: Don't call `$*REPO.installed` because only certain types of repos even have a `.installed` method, and you are generally interested if *any* repo can provide the given module (not just the current/head repo). It would be more appropriate to call e.g. `$*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.?installed)` but that wouldn't work with modules provided by a CURFS (`-I.`, `-Ilib`, etc)

Comment: Well there we go. I was literally just poking about at things to see what I could find.

Comment: `.resolve` `.load` and `.need` are notable because it will iterate over the entire repo chain, whereas all other methods like `.candidates` and `.installed` give results for the specific repo they are called on (hence using `$*REPO.repo-chain.map(*.?installed.Slip)`)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
my $loaded = False;
CATCH {
    default { $loaded = True }
}
require Optional::Module;
if ( ! $loaded ) {
  # Fail
}
# Go on
```

In this case it will try and load the module and catch the exception at runtime.

Comment: Isn't it the same as `try require Optional::Module`? What I wrote in my question should catch the exception at runtime.
I was looking for something like, say, a way to inspect the module repository (if that's really a better way), or something similar.

Comment: It is... I realised this after I wrote it but I figured I'd keep it as an answer.
Someone mentioned $*REPO in IRC yesterday. It's very lightly documented but a `.^methods` call on it gives some interesting results. You may want to look at that?